# Pinescript - Struggling to plot only last occurrence of change during an active condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am attempting to plot the highest value of an oscillator during an active condition.

At present, my red marker plots upon each new high during the condition.

What change do I need to make so that only the last occurrence of change during the condition is plotted (i.e. the prior marker is removed each time until the condition ends, at which point it remains fixed)?

I tried to create a float variable to allow each occurrence of the condition to have its own high.
This seemingly works but each change in high is being plotted within each occurrence of the condition, as opposed to the desired final change (i.e. the highest value).

Thank you.

(my head, firmly against brick wall.)
(oh and I do need to remove some redundant code here.)

```
var can_find = false
condstart = longinside == 1 and longinside[1] == 0
condstop = longinside[1] == 1 and longinside == 0
can_find := condstop ? false : condstart ? true : can_find
var float highesthigh = na
highesthigh := if (condstart)
    macd
else if longinside[1] == 1 and longinside == 1
    if (macd > highesthigh)
        macd
    else
        highesthigh
else if longinside[1] == 1 and longinside == 0
    na
var float lastHighestHigh = na
endofphrase = not na(highesthigh[1]) and na(highesthigh)
valueOfLastHighestHigh = ta.valuewhen(not na(highesthigh), highesthigh, 0)
if endofphrase
    lastHighestHigh := valueOfLastHighestHigh
lasthigh = ta.change(valueOfLastHighestHigh)
plotshape(lasthigh, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labeldown, color=(drawplotchar ? color.red : na), size=size.small, title='HIGH')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use label to plot your highest value and name it, so that you will be able to delete this label before draw a new one :

```
var label MyLabel = na
if MyCondition
    label.delete(MyLabel)
    MyLabel := label.new(bar_index, close, "My text", yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Once your condition is false, the last label drawn won't be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for this; I'll try it shortly. Is there no way of plotting the shape so that it only occurs after the condition has ended and plots at the last instance of a new high being made?

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you for putting me out of my misery.